# AngularJS Controllers dont work

Tags: angularjs, controllers

Using the latest ng library, I tried the following.

This file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Listing 4-2</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MyFilterDemoCtrl($scope) {

            var someData = {
                firstName: 'JENNA',
                surname: 'GRANT',
                dateJoined: new Date(2010, 2, 23),
                consumption: 123.659855,
                plan: 'super-basic-plan'
            };

            $scope.data = someData;

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app ng-controller="MyFilterDemoCtrl">

<p>
    <!-- Unfiltered data -->
    <strong>First Name</strong>: {{data.firstName}}<br/>
    <strong>Surname:</strong> {{data.surname}}
</p>

<p>
    <!-- Filtered data -->
    <strong>First Name</strong>: {{data.firstName | lowercase}}<br/>
    <strong>Surname:</strong> {{data.surname | lowercase }}
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Displays this output:

```
First Name: {{data.firstName}}
Surname: {{data.surname}}

First Name: {{data.firstName | lowercase}}
Surname: {{data.surname | lowercase }}
```

Why?

BTW - The MyFilterDemoCtrl controller’s only task here is to make the data available to the view. As you will recall from the last chapter, placing it in the scope does this.

Thanks.

J.

Comment: You should create angular module and then add controller into it  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: How? I copied this code from Apress AngularJS book: Publication Date: December 31, 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Angular about the controller, like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyFilterDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var someData = {
        firstName: 'JENNA',
        surname: 'GRANT',
        dateJoined: new Date(2010, 2, 23),
        consumption: 123.659855,
        plan: 'super-basic-plan'
    };

    $scope.data = someData;
}]);
```

Comment: You should also add ng-app="myApp"